# Implementation of "android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" broadcast receiver does not work in Xamarin

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

We are developing a Xamarin.Forms app. On the Android side, I am trying to implement a broadcast receiver for the "android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" intent so we can make sure it is registered with GCM after update. I put a notification in it to make sure the code was hit, but it does not appear. Any advice? Code will be below. I am deploying from VS to my Samsung Galaxy s5 on Android 6.0.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND", Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionMyPackageReplaced }, DataPath = "<package name>", DataScheme = "package")]
    public class GCMUpdateReceiver : GcmReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Bundle bundle = intent.Extras;
            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(Application.Context)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                .SetContentTitle("OnReceive")
                .SetContentText("ActionMyPackageReplaced")
                .SetAutoCancel(true);

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }

    }
```

Of note: I have done a clean before pushing to make sure the project is built and should be regarded as an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by combining with my other broadcast receiver and looking for Intent.ActionPackageReplaced and checking to make sure it was my package being replaced (instead of using ActionMyPackageReplaced, which I never received). My filters look like this:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND", Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE", "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION", "com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY" }, Categories = new string[] { "<package name>" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionPackageReplaced }, Categories = new string[] { "<package name>", Intent.CategoryDefault },
```